# shorten URL with mod_rewrite in .htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Basically all I want to do is this:

I have a URL to a PDF files on the server in this location:

```
http://chudz.co.uk/philaletheians.co.uk/Study%20notes/Atlantean%20Realities/Atlantis'%20study%20-%20Appendices%20and%20Notes.pdf
```

Now I want to remove this section of the URL:

```
/Study%20notes/Atlantean%20Realities/
```

This is what I have done in my htaccess file and it does not work:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/ /Study%20notes/Atlantean%20Realities/
```

I am new to this! as you can probably see above :) I have to keep the directory layout on the server as it is so my only option is to use mod_rewrite maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following to your .htaccess file in the root folder of your domain

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#if request does not already start with /Study notes/Atlantean Realities/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !^/Study\ notes/Atlantean\ Realities/ [NC]
#rewrite it to the /Study%20notes/Atlantean%20Realities/ directory
RewriteRule (.*) /Study\ notes/Atlantean\ Realities/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Hello I have tried the above but I just get internal server error 500.

Comment: I edited above to escape spaces from the directory and url, which you should get rid of if you can